# Parsing Output from Stripe_Charge Stripe Payments

Tags: php

The following output is a result of calling `var_export($charge)`;

How can I access the output of `'paid'=>true` from `$charge`?  Any ideas would be appreciated.

I have tried `$charge->_values->paid`, `$charge->paid`, etc.. I haven't had any luck.

I have also tried `$charge['_values']['paid']`;

```
Stripe_Charge::__set_state(array(
   '_apiKey' => 'sk_test_BPZyFpcAM',
   '_values' => 
  array (
    'id' => 'ch_102kMF29T6',
    'object' => 'charge',
    'created' => 1381688,
    'livemode' => false,
    'paid' => true,
    'amount' => 104000,
    'currency' => 'usd',
    'refunded' => false,
    'card' => 
    Stripe_Card::__set_state(array(
       '_apiKey' => 'sk_test_BPZyFpc',
       '_values' => 
      array (
        'id' => 'card_102kMF29T6',
        'object' => 'card',
        'last4' => '4242',
        'type' => 'Visa',
        'exp_month' => 2,
        'exp_year' => 2015,
        'fingerprint' => '7sRY4jiFM',
        'customer' => NULL,
        'country' => 'US',
        'name' => NULL,
        'address_line1' => NULL,
        'address_line2' => NULL,
        'address_city' => NULL,
        'address_state' => NULL,
        'address_zip' => NULL,
        'address_country' => NULL,
        'cvc_check' => 'pass',
        'address_line1_check' => NULL,
        'address_zip_check' => NULL,
      ),
       '_unsavedValues' => 
      Stripe_Util_Set::__set_state(array(
         '_elts' => 
        array (
        ),
      )),
       '_transientValues' => 
      Stripe_Util_Set::__set_state(array(
         '_elts' => 
        array (
        ),
      )),
       '_retrieveOptions' => 
      array (
      ),
    )),
    'captured' => true,
    'refunds' => 
    array (
    ),
    'balance_transaction' => 'txn_102kMF29T6Z',
    'failure_message' => NULL,
    'failure_code' => NULL,
    'amount_refunded' => 0,
    'customer' => NULL,
    'invoice' => NULL,
    'description' => 'admin@fra.org',
    'dispute' => NULL,
    'metadata' => 
    array (
    ),
  ),
   '_unsavedValues' => 
  Stripe_Util_Set::__set_state(array(
     '_elts' => 
    array (
    ),
  )),
   '_transientValues' => 
  Stripe_Util_Set::__set_state(array(
     '_elts' => 
    array (
    ),
  )),
   '_retrieveOptions' => 
  array (
  ),
))
```

Comment: I can access the value of true by calling var_dump($charge->paid);.

When I attempt to check if the value is true with if($charge->paid == true){ ... } the statement is never evaluated correctly.... why is true displaying with var_dump($charge->paid);, but when I check the condition it fails to evaluate?

Comment: I think this should be done using methods not direct access to vars.

Answer (score 13):

You can use the __toArray($recursive = false) function to get the data in array form.

Example:

```
$chargeArray = $charge->__toArray(true);
echo $chargeArray['paid'];
```

I was also able to access the object's data using an array structure before even converting to an array. For me, `$charge['paid']` gets me the value.

Comment: I also confirmed that simply doing $charge['paid'] works so it seems that's the easiest solution.

Comment: I can confirm this as well, and tried up-voting but managed to accidentally down-vote instead. sry :-/

Answer (score 2):

you can use `__toArray()` method:

```
$array = $collection->__toArray(true);
```

This will work for this case

Answer (score 1):

whatever returns please parse it with json_decode and you will get a assoc array in php
i.e suppose return array is $ret

```
$ret = json_decode($ret); 

$ret->paid;
$ret->captured;
$ret->card->id; 
and so on..
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo gettype($charge->paid); //boolean
var_dump($charge->paid); //bool(true)

if($charge->paid==true)echo "==true"; //==true
if($charge->paid===true)echo "===true"; //===true
if($charge->paid==1)echo "==1"; //==1
if($charge->paid===1)echo "===1"; //nada, it's a boolean, not numeric
```

So using `if($charge->paid===true)`, you should be guaranteed that you are testing what you want to know.

Here in the output via print_r, you can see that paid is displayed as 1.

```
 [_values:protected] => Array ( [id] => ch_10as29724hknftGBm9TxC [object] => charge [created] => 1384696845 [livemode] => [paid] => 1 [amount] => 1400
```

Thus, depending on where and how paid is being evaluated, it may appear as a number, string, or a boolean. You could run a series of tests for the three possibilities, or just use `if($charge->paid){...}`

When paid is false, it would probably be returned as empty (""), 0, or a boolean false. A possible thing to look out for is the boolean false being transposed to a string, in which case it would be interpreted as true.

```
$val = "false";
if($val){
    echo "true"; //true
}
```

So, in your test, just add intval($val) to normalize the values and be on the safe side.

`if(intval($charge->paid)){...}`

Cheers