# Parsing Output from Stripe return Stripe Payments

Tags: payment, gateway

I am using a payment gateway stripe. I have implemented this but the return payment array is not parse-able by me. I have print_r() this and array structure really horrible to parse by me.

Please suggest me to parse this array.

Answer (score 0):

whatever returns please parse it with json_decode and you will get a assoc array in php i.e suppose return array is $ret

```
$ret = json_decode($ret); 

$ret->paid;
$ret->captured;
$ret->card->id; 
and so on..
```

Hope it will help you.

([Parsing Output from Stripe_Charge Stripe Payments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19347444/parsing-output-from-stripe-charge-stripe-payments/22371775#22371775))

Comment: $ret = json_decode($ret); 

This one helps me to get this array